# Is it possible for the same javac compiler to compile the same set of source files but produce class files of different checksums?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, ant, maven, checksum

I was attempting to compare the results of this: (in ant)

```
                       <javac 
                           target="1.5"   
                           source="1.5"
                           deprecation="on"
                           fork="yes"
                           optimize="true"
                           debug="true"
                           debuglevel="lines,vars,source">

                            <classpath>
                                <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/../lib">
                                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                                    <include name="**/*.zip" />
                                </fileset>                        
                            </classpath>     
                        </javac>
```

...against this: (in maven)

```
        <plugin>                
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>                
                    <configuration>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                        <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <optimize>true</optimize>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <includes>
                            ...
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

...only to discover that 2 of the resulting class files have slightly different checksums, while the rest are identical. I consider multi-threading to have played a part, but the checksums produced for either option appear to be consistent upon repeated attempts. What can possibly account for this result?

**Update:**

I have examined one set of the files with different checksums using `javap -verbose` and noticed the only difference being:

```
const #16 = class   #108;   //  java/lang/Exception
const #17 = Method  #102.#109;  //  java/io/Writer.close:()V
const #18 = Method  #7.#109;    //  java/io/FileWriter.close:()V
```

as opposed to:

```
const #16 = Method  #102.#108;  //  java/io/Writer.close:()V
const #17 = Method  #7.#108;    //  java/io/FileWriter.close:()V
const #18 = class   #109;   //  java/lang/Exception
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the contents of the files?

Comment: I would: (1) make sure both are picking up exactly the same Java compiler; (2) capture & compare the two sets of options that are passed to the compiler.

Comment: @aix I have tried with different compilers and verified the java version in the manifest file at the subsequent jar step, so I doubt (1) is the cause. Do you know of any good ways to achieve (2)?

Comment: @prusswan: Not sure. Perhaps create a shell script called `javac` that would dump its arguments and then call the real `javac`.

Comment: While I doubt this is your problem, annotation processors could cause the same javac compiler to produce class files with different checksums.

Comment: I dont know if java requires it, but I could imagine that even multiple compilations of the same source with the same compiler doenst generate the same code. I could imagine that symboltable, constpools, etc. are internal stored as hash maps, which dont yield a deterministic iteration order. So when generting code for them, it maybe happens with the same source file and same compiler that different code is emitted. Did you have same checksum on different runs with the same compiler on the sources?

Comment: @flolo I tried a few times. It appears that the checksums are consistent for either option (ant/maven) on repeated attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you showed, the difference is in the generated constant pool, which is really a non-issue, but troubling as you would expect the same output with the same compiler and options.  i would bet that the compiler is called with the java files in different order between the two situations, and the order of compilation is affecting the result.

Comment: is there a good way to assert a particular order of compilation? so that the same result can be obtained no matter which way is used?

Comment: maybe if you list out each include file individually.  do you really need that, though?

Comment: may or may not, I am mostly concerned about two things: if such difference has any impact on program behavior / will any eyebrows be raised later on, by people who may classify this as a bug

Answer (score 0):

I'm using javac compiler and I've found it produces different resulting binary .class files depending on the order of the source files passed as parameter. Between maven and ant I found differences. The order of the files were not the same.

Anyway, between the 2 compilations there were differences. I've disassembled the code and I found the javac (optimizer?) was removing the deprecated java jsr/ret assembly instructions from one of the compilations.

I don't know if this behaviour it's the result of "implicit" compilation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html#searching