# Ant compiling wrong version after git checkout

Tags: git, ant

I found a strange behaviour in an ant build of a git repository. Here's what i do:
I have 2 branches in the git repository, "master" and "dev", where I commit all the changes before the final release. After a few commits I found myself with this situation:

```
*----*---------*-----* dev
|    |         |
|    (commit)  (commit)
master
```

From dev branch I build a jar with an ant script and then I save it for later.
Then I checkout master, I do "merge dev" (with fast forward) and I build again the jar file with the same script.

If I try to compare the two jars (one made from dev branch, one from "merged" master) with winmerge I find some class file with different content.

I really don't understand what's happening, shouldn't be the two jars identical, since they are built from the same sources? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question

[Is it possible for the same javac compiler to compile the same set of source files but produce class files of different checksums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769319/is-it-possible-for-the-same-javac-compiler-to-compile-the-same-set-of-source-fil)

some aspects of a class file are dependent on the order in which the sources are compiled.

On top of that: Does Winmerge ignore the different timestamps in the jar files?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Winmerge extracts the content of the two jar files and it successfully identifies the different timestamps of the class files. However different timestamps don't affect the comparation between class files. That is if two class files are equal but with different timestamps they are marked as identical.