# Is the class file generated by javac always the same?

Tags: javac

Currently we are in the process of re-scripting all of our build system for a large project (around 2000 source files) and there has been talk of doing a binary comparison on the files to ensure that everything is correct which leads to the following question: **Is the output of `javac` guaranteed to be same across compilations or could it be subject to change?**

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769319/is-it-possible-for-the-same-javac-compiler-to-compile-the-same-set-of-source-fil) implied that the constant pool could have a different order, but assuming we are able to control for the order of the files going into the `javac` call is there still a potential for differences? We are using Ant and Maven as part of the build if that may influence things as well.

Comment: Not guaranteed.  In practice it would probably be identical if you use the identical compiler and compile-time JAR structure, but even minor changes to JAR order, etc, could upset the applecart.

Comment: Wouldn't your tests ensure *functional* equivalence, which is what you're actually concerned about? In any case, why not just try it and see what happens? If you find stuff has been re-ordered, you'll have to go in and do byte-code analysis to see if they're byte-code-equivalent anyway.

Comment: Really wonder why would you need to do a binary comparison of built classes?

Comment: Like I said--just try it. If it turns out there are differences, then you'll need to drop to the byte-code level; that will at least work for determining if all the methods/constants/etc. are accounted for. I don't know *why* a method, say, might be compiled differently, *all other things being equal*, but if they're not, then you're screwed.

Comment: My imagination is failing to came with any explanation how binary comparison could replace the test coverage. am I missing something?

Comment: So, what question would that be?

Comment: I'm curious what sort of problem you would expect to catch by doing this comparison.  Presumably you would expect some files to be different from one build to another, since the source would have changed.  What other causes of bytecode differences would you be looking for?  If the source hasn't changed, and the compilation is successful, why would you care whether the bytecode is identical to the prior build?

Comment: Guys, he's talking about changing the *build system*, not his actual code base! So ensuring that the build system produces functionally-equivalent results before and after the change means checking that the built files are actually equivalent. Obviously the unit tests on the actual code will tell you a lot, but it could give you real peace of mind to know that the build system is producing the same binary results after the configuration change.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov - I the actual question in bold text, "Does `javac` always generate the same output or can it be different given different versions of javac (i.e. OpenJDK vs. Oracle)?"

Comment: @DaveCosta - The group is actually split right now, some of us think it's a waste of time ("As long as it runs, who cares if it's the same?") and the other have wants full verification of the build system ("Identical output means that the output must be identical at the binary level!"). Between both the groups there are a couple of us burning cycles trying to find out if the Java spec even indicates that the byte code is guaranteed to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bytecode is absolutely *not* guaranteed to be the same; for one thing, compilers are allowed to perform optimizations that don't affect any guaranteed behaviors. The Java Language Specification even mentions, in a few places, optimizations that a compiler might perform; for example, of the string concatenation operator `+`, it notes that:

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate `String` object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the `StringBuffer` class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate `String` objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.

[[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)]

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on the compiler, but I tend to believe the other answers saying that binary comparison is not 100% reliable.

I'd consider another alternative:  You should be able to inspect the artifacts your build system creates (.jars & .wars, etc.) and ensure that each have the expected contents, and even that the size of each file is within a fairly tight tolerance.

If your build script is generating source and compiling it, then you should be able to do comparisons against the generated source, which I expect *would* be 100% stable from build to build.  (Or at least predictable).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to assure equivalence is to get one of the several class file parsers, parse the files, then do the heavy work of figuring out differences due to constant pool order changes, etc.  The main problem is that reordering the constant pool will change numeric values that reference the constants, some of which are in table elements, some of which are in bytecodes.  Doable, but definitely non-trivial, and probably not practical unless you already have most of the framework in place for some other reason (such as bytecode modification).