# How to prove that class file matches java file

Tags: java, compilation

I recently accidentally submitted my `.class` file instead of the `.java` file for an assignment.

After feedback from the grader, I submitted my `.java` file.  Everything worked out fine from there, the grader trusted that it was an honest mistake.

However, is there a simple way for the grader to check to see if the two files really match up?

So far, I've only thought of two solutions:

1. Compile the `.java`, and see if the `.class` outputted is identical/very similar.  This is probably very compiler dependant.  If the compilers were the same, are there other variables that would make the `.class` different?
2. Decompile the `.class` file, and do a character comparison. This seems like a lot more work, and probably match the `.java` file even less than solution 1.

Is there a reliable way to check this?

Comment: Option 1) Probably will not work due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928330/is-the-class-file-generated-by-javac-always-the-same

Comment: @merlin2011 If there was a 99% match, that's still a reasonable assurance that they are the same, no?  Is it reasonable to assume that the same class will be 99% similar?

Comment: If 1) isn't enough, you could compile the java, then decompile both .class files and compare the decompiled results - they should be identical if they were from the same .java file.

Comment: @NathanMerrill, I would not be entirely sure about that, because a newer compiler might optimize a lot heavier, especially if the code is complex.

Comment: @stvcisco I think that that is better solution than #2.  I like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with the exact same compiler in the exact same enviornment, it is highly likely that you will get identical class files.

However, if there are variations in compiler or platform, you should look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928330/is-the-class-file-generated-by-javac-always-the-same).

Outside of that, you will probably have to evaluate it functionally. That is, write a test class that exercises all desired behaviors of each class and check whether they all return identical results.

Comment: Checking the class functionally is a fantastic idea to check to see if class really is the same.  However, in this case, it was a pretty silly program where no input was given, and it always produced the same output (it was a demonstration of algorithms).

Comment: @NathanMerrill, Perhaps you could combine such an approach with decompilation to see whether the logic matched or not, but I do not think you would be able to automate that part.

Answer (score -2):

I did a very simple test and it worked for me..

I compiled a simple java program and created its `.class` file
Then I just change one letter inside `System.out.println` and again crated a `.class` file

Then used `diff` command in linux and it tells me that `two binary files are different`

So I think instead of decompiling the `.class` file and then checking both `.java` files you can directly check for two .class files

At least it worked for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would hope that different `.java` files would produce different `.class` files.  The issue is identical `.java` files producing different `.class` files